# HDF5 file data to JPG image conversion

Tags: python, matlab, hdf5, h5py

I have a number of *HDF5* files that I want to convert the data inside these files to *JPG* or *PNG* format.
This is my  [*HDF5* files link](https://www.creatis.insa-lyon.fr/Challenge/IEEE_IUS_2016/sites/www.creatis.insa-lyon.fr.Challenge.IEEE_IUS_2016/files/in_vivo.zip).

These files are from the *PICMUS* challenge and the only way to open them is through the *MATLAB* codes provided in this [link](https://www.creatis.insa-lyon.fr/Challenge/IEEE_IUS_2016/sites/www.creatis.insa-lyon.fr.Challenge.IEEE_IUS_2016/files/archive_to_download.zip).

However, I need to open these files in *Python* or at least convert the data inside them into *PNG* or *JPG* images so that I can use them in my *Python* project.

I tried different ways but none of them worked. Can anyone convert these files for me or at least tell me how to open them?

Please provide me a detailed solution.

Comment: I don't think you are going to find any help here.   I took a quick look at the files and they are not straight forward image data.  They are some kind of raw ultrasound data & the Matlab code doesn't appear to be straight forward either.  You should read the link below and simplify your questions to something more specific.   [ask]

Comment: You could open the images in Matlab then save them to PNG files.
Matlab's [imwrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) should help you to save the images.